# Copy and paste between special lines using awk command

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a problem with `awk` in this command

```
awk 'NR==1,/mode/{next}/tot/,NR==0{next}{print}' 1.out > 2.dat
```

From the contents of file 1, I put the lines between the line that starts with the word `mode` and the line that starts with the word `tot` in file 2.

Now I want to put this data that I am copying from file 1 in another file like file 3 (which already exists and has contents) between the lines that start with the specific words `mode` and `tot`.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that the given `awk` command

```
awk 'NR==1,/mode/{next}/tot/,NR==0{next}{print}' 1.out > 2.dat
```

was executed, and created file `2.dat`.

In order to modify an existing file `3.out` as requested, here is the answer using one `awk` command (to create a temporary file `/tmp/3.out.tmpfile`):

```
awk 'FNR==1{nf++}; NR==1,/mode/{print;next}; f2==0{f2=1;nextfile}; nf==2{print;next}; /tot/,0{print}' 3.out 2.dat 3.out > /tmp/3.out.tmpfile
```

and one `mv` command (to replace the original `3.out` file by the modified one `/tmp/3.out.tmpfile`):

```
mv /tmp/3.out.tmpfile 3.out
```

For example, if the original `3.out` file contains:

```
line-1
line-2
mode
line-X
line-Y
line-Z
tot
line-3
line-4
line-5
```

and file `2.dat` contains:

```
inserted-line-A
inserted-line-B
inserted-line-C
inserted-line-D
inserted-line-E
```

then the above proposed commands will result in a modified `3.out` file that now contains:

```
line-1
line-2
mode
inserted-line-A
inserted-line-B
inserted-line-C
inserted-line-D
inserted-line-E
tot
line-3
line-4
line-5
```

The original `3.out` lines between `mode` and `tot` have now been replaced by the ones in file `2.dat`.

Comment: Thank you very much I gauss this wirk for me

Comment: @naderahmadvand If this answer solves your issue, please accept it as the solution by clicking the gray checkmark next to it. Thanks!